# Django admin custom form in create,update,view based on parent-child table relation

Tags: django-admin

I have one table called product and it is having field category based on category i will have to save relevant information in correct category table

table like below

```
class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=36)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    code = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=31)
    category = models.ForeignKey('ProductCategory', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='category')


class CategoryOneProduct(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=36)
    product = models.OneToOneField('Product', models.DO_NOTHING, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    traffic_code = models.IntegerField()
    routing = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

i want to build admin UI which will display field from category table based on category and same thing i will have to achieve in create ,update , display

is it possible to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after lots of searching i found Stackedinline and tabularinline facility provided by Django which is giving above ability to show the required data